# UIRefreshControl on UIViewController WITHOUT table or collectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, tableview, uirefreshcontrol

Had never needed this before but,

Is there a way (or library out there) that allows me to use a refresh control on a UIViewController that does not contain a table or collectionView?

been looking around for a while and see no answer to this one.

any help is appreciated

Comment: How would it work on UIViewController? Are you going to wrap it up into UIScrollView? if so then what's your target iOS version?
Starting from iOS10, you can add refreshControl for UIScrollView.
If you need earlier iOS version support, there are plenty of answers in stackoverflow, with bunch of code which is allowing to add refresh control into scrollview

Comment: bingo! the app is  >= iOS10 is you mark it as an answer i'll accept it as such

Comment: It's fine, glad it helped :)